# How to run full directories in phpunit?

Tags: php, tdd, phpunit

I have somewhat complex dir structure for my tests.
En example:

```
unitests

unitests/moduleA
unitests/moduleA/t1.php
unitests/moduleA/t2.php
unitests/moduleA/t3.php


unitests/moduleB
unitests/moduleB/t1.php
unitests/moduleB/t2.php
unitests/moduleB/t3.php
```

I might have deeper directory structure.

How would I run ALL the tests in one command?

(I tried `phpunit unitests/*/*` which ran only the first file found `unitests/moduleA/t1.php`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a configuration file, it will make things easier to run the tests in the future.

If you create a `phpunit.xml` file containing :

```
<phpunit>
<testsuites>

<testsuite name="Unit">
<directory>unitests/*</directory>
</testsuite>

</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

and run `phpunit`, all tests should run.

You should also suffix all your classes with `Test`.

Also it's not a bad idea to create a test suite per sub-folder.

Comment: Where is best practice to put this config? in my `unitest` folder?

Comment: Most project put it in the root folder of the library.

For example : 
phpunit.xml
src/
tests/
So you can run the phpunit command from the root folder directly.

Comment: Funny, I did what u said with naming the test classes and the respective files, and this did the trick, even if I remove the XML. But, if I do it from withing the unitest folder, then the XML becomes necessary, Nice - thanks!

Comment: Yes, all test classes have to be prefixed with Test to be recognized by phpunit. I thought there were an issue in the path too.